# get alert message on entering the same email which is present in database in validating form VB project (preventing the duplicate values)?

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

How get an alert message on entering the same email which is present in a database in validating form VB project (preventing the duplicate values)?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box-warning">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">General Elements</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="col-md-8">
              <form role="form" runat="server">
                <!-- text input -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Enter your name</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="txtname" runat="server" placeholder="Enter your Name"/>
                </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="txtemail" runat="server" placeholder="Enter your Email"/>
                </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                  <label>User name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="txtusername"  runat="server" placeholder="Enter your Username"/>
                </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="txtpassword" runat="server" placeholder="Enter your Password"/>
                </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Confirm Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm" id="txtconfirm" runat="server" placeholder="Confirm your Password"/>

                </div>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="button_Click" />
                </form>
                    </div>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And above is the HTML code I want an alert message on repeated entering of email id means same email id if I enter it has to alert.

```
{
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqlcon"].ToString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_insertUserDetails", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", objbo.name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", objbo.email);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", objbo.username);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", objbo.password);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@confrimPassword", objbo.confrimPassword);

                    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    con.Close();
                    if(result > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
```

Here is my database of this form. From which i need to compare the data.

```
create table Info( id int identity(1,1)   primary key (id), name varchar(50),email varchar(50),
 username nvarchar(50),password nvarchar(50),confrimPassword nvarchar(50));

 select *  from Info;


go
create Procedure Sp_insertUserDetails
 (
 @name Varchar(200),
 @email  Varchar(200),
 @username nVarchar(50),
 @password nvarchar(50),
 @confrimPassword nvarchar(50))
 As
 Begin
   Insert into Info(name, email, username, password,confrimPassword)
   Values(@name, @email, @username, @password,@confrimPassword)
 End

 select *
 from Info;
 drop Procedure Sp_insertUserDetails;
```

Comment: If its VB code you should edit your tags. You should probably add asp.net webforms to your tags as well.

Comment: sir need this to works as when i enter the same email which is already present in the database then it has to alert a message telling that invalid how to add this jQuery. please help.

Comment: Hi @thejaswini, did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is add a asp.net label to the html, with the visible property set to false, then use this label to display a validation message when the user clicks save and the email address already exists.  Try adding the following code to btnSubmit:

```
if (DoesEmailAlreadyExist(txtemail.Text))
{
    lblWarning.Text = "The email already exists";
    lblWarning.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    // save the data using your existing code
}
```

To check if the email address already exists, create a new stored procedure.  something like:

```
create Procedure Sp_doesEmailExist
 (
 @email  Varchar(200),
 @Exists char(1) output)
 As
 Begin
   if exists (SELECT * FROM Info where Email = @email)
    begin
        SELECT @Exists = 'Y'
    end
    else
    begin
        SELECT @Exists = 'N'
    end
 End
go
```

You can use the following code to call the stored procedure.

```
public bool DoesEmailAlreadyExist(string email)
    {
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqlcon"].ToString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_doesEmailExist", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                    SqlParameter p = cmd.Parameters.Add("@exists", SqlDbType.Char, 1);
                    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    return cmd.Parameters["@exists"].Value.ToString() == "Y";
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```